# Copy a range of data to all sheets of the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains a database .

On that database there is a certain row of  data that i would like to copy and paste to all sheets.

The copying range varies as the row data on the database changes, but the paste range for each location remains the same.

I have a code that i have done so far but it only allows to copy paste sheet by sheet and i could not define a fixed range in the code.

In this case i would like the selected data to be pasted to B1:N1 of each sheet.

Some help would be needed to paste at one goal to all sheets.

Here is my code:

```
Dim rng As Range, inp As Range
Set rng = Nothing
Set inp = Selection
inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    rng.Parent.Activate
    rng.Select
    inp.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you need a Loop for all worksheets ?

```
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = "*Name of the database workbook *" Then    
            Call ws.Range("B1:N1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I am getting a method paste of object worksheet failed on the ws.Paste("B1:N1")

Comment: try `ws.Paste(ws.Range("B1:N1"))`

Comment: no i didnt change. anyways to incporporate paste link?

Comment: My bad, actually the Range object doesn't have a paste method, only the worksheet has it. So it's `ws.Paste Link:=True` or `ws.Range(B1:N1).Pastespecial` (see Edit)

Comment: it pastes but i am not getting the values, its all 0s on the rest of the worksheets

Comment: what is in the inp Range ? why do you select the rng Range ?

Comment: inp range is the range selected through the use of input box

Comment: No, in your code, the inp range refers to the range that you selected when you start the macro. If you want the range of the input box, use the rng Range. `rng.Copy` and not `inp.Copy` or declare the inputBox as following : `Set Inp = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Rng As Range, _
    Inp As Range, _
    wS As Worksheet

Set Inp = Selection
Inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If TypeName(Rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    Rng.Parent.Activate
    Inp.Copy

    For Each wS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        wS.Range("B1").Paste Link:=True
    Next
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = 0
```

Comment: I am getting an object does not support this property or method on the ws.Range("B1"). Paste Link:=True